# How to remove duplicates?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a dynamic tab and table headers from an xml file,

The tab name is goign to be "Adapter" or so forth to show up only once ie ignore any duplicates Tab names

Similar for the header names for the table as well

How can I remove teh duplicate tabs and header title?
Currently the output generated form the script below:

**Adapters <- TAB**

**TargetClass | TargetName  | DisplayName | AdminStatus | OperStatus | Type |**

Interface | IF   | IF | UP | UP | EMAC | Normal|

**Adapters - <- TAB**

**TargetClass | TargetName  | DisplayName | AdminStatus | OperStatus | Type |**

Interface | IF   | IF | UP | UP | EMAC | Alert|

**Adapters - <-TAB**

**TargetClass | TargetName  | DisplayName } AdminStatus | OperStatus | Type |**

Network | IF   | IF | UP | UP | EMAC | NA|

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "view.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    complete: function(data,status) { parseXml(data.responseXML); }
  });
});

function parseXml(xml)
{


  $(xml).find("cView").each(function()
  {
     $("#output").append('<b>' + $(this).attr("type") + " - TAB CView type </b><br />");


    $(this).find("field").each(function()
    {
      $("#output").append('<b>' +$(this).attr("name") + " -- </b>");    
    //  $("#output").append($(this).text() + " -- ");

    });
    $("#output").append("<br />");
    $(this).find("field").each(function()
    {
      //$("#output").append('<b>' +$(this).attr("name") + " -- </b>");  
      $("#output").append($(this).text() + " -- ");
    });

    $("#output").append("<br /><br/>");
  });  

}
```

XML bit

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed>
    <entry>
    ----
    ----
    <cView type="D1">
                    <field name="TargetObjectClass">Disk</field>
                    <field name="TargetObjectName">DISK A1</field>
                    <field name="DisplayName">DISK-Name</field>
                    <field name="MaxAvgDataRate KB/sec">50.00 KB/sec</field>
                    <field name="MaxAvgQueueDepth">50.00</field>
                </cView>
                <cView type="D1">
                    <field name="TargetObjectClass">Disk</field>
                    <field name="TargetObjectName">DISK B2</field>
                    <field name="DisplayName"> Disk-Name 2 </field>
                    <field name="MaxAvgDataRate KB/sec">60.00 KB/sec</field>
                    <field name="MaxAvgQueueDepth">60.00</field>
                </cView>


    ...
    </entry>
</feed>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question too well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what elements need to be clean, but maybe are you looking for that :

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/

Comment: The elements i am trying to clean are D1s ,  and also for the element field name="TargetObjectClass"  both teh D1 have TargetObjectClass, I am going to  use the name to create a table header so it cannot be duplicate as well

Comment: In a general way, the algorithm to detect duplicate is to sort your collection and run through it to see if an element is the same as the previous. So you can create an array with your elements, sort it by the good field, and run through it to remove duplicates.